# How does Auto regressive neural network work?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, autoregressive

can anyone please give me some idea or links as to how the autoregressive neural networks work for time series?

I tried to go through the thesis of Sebastian Dietz, but I could not able to understand the network intuitively.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [this video](http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/video-archive/static/2017/01/2267-16372/mergedvideo.ogv) of Hugo Larochelle.

In a nutshell, autoregressive neural network are designed to predict some dimensions given a subset of other dimensions; for example in images, to predict one pixel given a subset of other pixels; for time series, to predict one time sample given a subset of time samples.

Note that for time series, some models do not restrict to the *natural* ordering of the dimensions, and are trained to predict one time sample given *both* past and future time samples.

Examples includes NADE, PixelCNN, PixelRNN, ...